# Loading Google Analytics 2 Years historical data via API using CC Rest connector

Tags: gooddata

I am wondering if there is a way to pull Google Analytics un-sampled historical data for 2 years via API using CC Rest connector component. Unfortunately the GA account is a standard and not a premium so I can not get around 500K limit.

It would be great if GoodData Developer team can share an ETL graph file to solve this request. It is a common use case per clients.

Thanks,
Andy

Comment: I will try to find and prepare something to help you. Give you answer as soon as possible!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have discovered this kind of [solution](https://developer.gooddata.com/downloads/cloud-connect/examples/googleanalytics-history.zip).

Run the `ga_00_master graph` that will run multiple time the `ga_01_sub graph`. For each day you want to have the data it will send a request to `Google Analytics` and gives you a file with the data for that day.

There are few things to do

- fill in GA_CONNECTION to sub graph
- and link parameter file ga_params.prm
- and parameters

for master graph:

```
GA_MIN_DATE = "yyyy-MM-dd"
```

for sub graph:

```
PROFILE_NUMBER
```